# Encoding a tuple of strings into integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to write by first Neural network from scratch using 2 inputs (length and width) to give the output (r/b). **I want to encode the strings r and b into integers 0 and 1** so that I have an output vector. Without using a pre-made function like labelenconder.

`length = np.array((3,2,4,3,3.5,2,5.5,1,4.5))
width = np.array((1.5,1,1.5,1,.5,.5,1,1,1))
c =('r','b','r','b','r','b','r','b','?')`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly quickly like so:

```
my_matcher = {'r':0, 'b':1}

new_input = [my_matcher.get(val) for val in c]
```

If you need it to be a tuple, you can wrap it with `tuple(new_input)`

Comment: Or `list(map(my_matcher.get, c))`.

Comment: Other than the notation being more succinct, what's the advantage of `map`? Is it faster? I haven't familiarized myself with that function too much

Comment: It's marginally fast because `dict.get` is a built-in. But some may find it more readable, especially if you're using it as an iterator, i.e. `map(my_matcher.get, c)`.